# Math.pow with Command line arguments

Tags: java, math, command-line

I need to get the power value of a given number by user (as a command line argument)

This is my code and it has comes up with a compilation error.

Can anyone please help me ?

```
class SquareRoot{

      public static void main(String args []){

          double power = Math.pow(args[0]);         
          System.out.println("Your squared value is " + power);

      }
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone call Math.pow(x, 2.0)?  Better to write it as x*x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Math.pow needs two arguments. Something like:

```
double power = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(args[0]),2.0);
```

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

Comment: Considering the name of the class, the second argument is probably 0.5

Comment: @assylias Good catch, in that case he can also use: `Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(args[0]))`  :)

Answer (score 5):

`Math.pow` takes in two args, you would have to have take two numbers from the command line or have one "hard coded".

This is the signature :

```
public static double pow(double a, double b)
```

Answer (score 3):

`args[0]` is a `String` you need to convert it to double. You can use `Double.parseDouble()`

Check the syntax of [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

```
double power = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(args[0]), Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
```

You need to pass two arguments `base` and `exponent`.  Or for square you will have value for second parameter as `2`

```
double power = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(args[0]), 2);
```

Also your name of the class is `SqaureRoot` not `square` so second parameter needs to be

```
 double power = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(args[0]), 0.5);
```

Or simply use [Math.sqrt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)

```
double squareroot = Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(args[0]));
```

Comment: Or more likely, the command line needs to pass in 2 arguments.

Comment: @AmitD You are not computing the squared value.

Comment: Still an error is there :( Error : pow(double,double) in java.lang.math cannot be applied to (int)

Answer (score 2):

`Math#pow(double a, double b)` where `ab`

```
double power = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(args[0]),2);
```